# Docker Compose : NodeJS + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I can't make my docker compose work.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:0.12
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD . /myapp
RUN npm install
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - 27017
web:
  build: .
  command: npm start
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    PORT: 3000
```

And in server.js:

```
  var MONGO_DB;
  var DOCKER_DB = process.env.DB_1_PORT;
  if ( DOCKER_DB ) {
    MONGO_DB = DOCKER_DB.replace( "tcp", "mongodb" ) + "/dev_db";
  } else {
    MONGO_DB = process.env.MONGODB;
  }

  mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB);
```

as from duplicated from this repo: https://github.com/projectweekend/Node-Backend-Seed
but `process.env.DB_1_PORT` is empty. **How can I add it?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we use `docker-compose.yml` and for reliable connection web service with `db` (mondoDB in this case) the final `MONGO_DB` connection string should look like (without authorization and additional args) as the following:

```
mongodb://db:27017/myapp
```

where:

- db - name of the docker-composer MongoDB service
- myapp - name of the mongoDB database

More see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011552/mongodb-on-with-docker-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-c)

Comment: Correct. this was visible in the comments but indeed it is better to have a proper answer for this. Cheers

Answer (score 25):

Sorry @gettho.child, I accepted your answer too quickly. I thought it was working but it wasn't. I'll report here my final solution since I have been struggling quite some to achieve it.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:0.12
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev libkrb5-dev
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD package.json /myapp/package.json
RUN npm install
ADD . /myapp
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
db:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
web:
  build: .
  command: node app.js
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    PORT: 3000 # this is optional, allows express to use process.env.PORT instead of a raw 3000
```

And the interesting app.js extracts:

```
var MONGO_DB;
var DOCKER_DB = process.env.DB_PORT;
if ( DOCKER_DB ) {
  MONGO_DB = DOCKER_DB.replace( 'tcp', 'mongodb' ) + '/myapp';
} else {
  MONGO_DB = process.env.MONGODB;
}
var retry = 0;
mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Regarding the `process.env.DB_PORT` I've tried many things around. If it doesn't work out-of-the-box, I suggest to `console.log(process.env);` and look for mongo's IP.

The final URL should look like: `mongodb://172.17.0.76:27017/myapp`

Good luck, it is worth it, Docker's awesome!

---

EDIT:

If the above works, I now found a techno-agnostic workflow by running:

- `docker-compose run web /bin/bash`
- and in there running `printenv`

I hope this is not too much self promotion but I wrote a double article on the topic which may help some of the readers: https://augustin-riedinger.fr/en/resources/using-docker-as-a-development-environment-part-1/

Cheers

Comment: the port under environment should be declared like `PORT=3000`, that turns it into an environment variable on build.  you can test by going `echo $PORT` which should produce `3000`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I commented in the `docker-compose.yml`: `# this is optional, allows express to use process.env.PORT instead of a raw 3000`

Comment: I think what @GHETTO.CHiLD is saying is that 
      PORT: 3000  should be - PORT=3000.  My apologies I dont know how to format this answer.

Comment: @GHETTO.CHiLD both ways work https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/yml/#environment

Comment: About the final URL. It could be `mongodb://<db image name>:27017/myapp` in your case `mongodb://db:27017/myapp` should work. +1 for the great question and answer.

Comment: Now I systematically enter my docker by running `docker-compose run web /bin/bash` and there makes a `printenv`. I detailed it all in a double blog article for those who are curious: https://augustin-riedinger.fr/en/resources/using-docker-as-a-development-environment-part-1/

Comment: links is deprecated, dont use it anymore.

Comment: @Tsangares what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that mongoDB IP (and port) in your 'Server.js' file is set to 'PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR' (check port too) - can be found when running 'docker exec {web app container id} env'.

Comment: Indeed. Now I don't bother anymore. I run `docker-compose run web /bin/bash` and make `printenv` of whatever in the container!

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose should be

```
environment:
   - MONGODB=3000
```

See [this link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#environment) for more information on mapping environment variables.  You are declaring the environment variable as `PORT` instead of `MONGODB`.

Comment: Not sure of why it should work, but it actually does.

Comment: In fact it didn't, sorry. I reported my answer.