# MongoDB on with Docker "failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am using mongoDB with and NodeJS backend. The Problem is I am getting the following error

> node:16) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed
>   to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
>   [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

This is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

  rest-api-node:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    links:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
```

I have tried with `depends_on` as well , was not working.

On backend I am mongoose as a middleware to communicate with DB. this is the part of my `index.js`

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/demo')
app.listen(port, () => console.log("live"))
```

I have tried using promise as well , no change though. Please Help me out.
Thanks in advance

complete error log

> at Pool.
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:505:11)
>   rest-api-node_1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:180:13) rest-api-node_1
>   |     at Connection.
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:329:12)
>   rest-api-node_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
>   rest-api-node_1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:180:13)
>   rest-api-node_1  |     at Socket.
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:245:50)
>   rest-api-node_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
>   rest-api-node_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
>   rest-api-node_1  |     at emitErrorNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8) rest-api-node_1  |     at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
>   rest-api-node_1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError', rest-api-node_1  |
>   message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first
>   connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]' }

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> By default [Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name.

According to your `docker-compose.yaml` file you can access you mongo container on `127.0.0.1:27017` only from host machine. 
In order to access it from  NodeJS backend container you should use `db:27017`.

Comment: What do you mean by `db:27017`?

Comment: I believe it's the mongo url. I was facing the same issue. Inside the container there is no `localhost`. You have to change the url to `mongodb://db:27017/demo`. That solved my problem.

Comment: `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.mongo.ports is invalid: Invalid port "db:27017", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]` -- the above suggestion causes this error. i also tried the name of the DB i'm using.

Comment: @ChumiestBucket I don't understand why you voted -1 to the answer? You don't need to change above docker-compose.yml. When you changed it you got the error. My post is about application setting where we define url to a mongodb container. It should be 'db:27017' instead of 'localhost:27017'.

Comment: @nickgryg my bad, i misunderstood this

Comment: This `mongodb://db:27017/demo` worked for me. Thx nickgryg

Comment: How would this work if your docker-compose has a user and password?

Comment: Rajesh Barik you just save my life

Answer (score 22):

I have the same problem, other solutions not work for me but I did that this way

### Note :

for mongo URI you must use your MongoDB `service name` instead `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`

for example, in below docker-compose file my mongo service name is `mongodb-myapp` and I change URI like this `mongodb://mongodb-myapp:27017/myapp` and it works for me

```yaml
services:
  boilerplate-api-app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb-myapp:27017/myapp
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-myapp

 mongodb-myapp:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 2):

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  node-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=imran
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=test_password
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

The above code is the docker-compose.yaml file and the service name for the MongoDB is 'mongo'. You don't have to manually insert the IP address of the container. Instead of that just insert the service name in the MongoDB URI like this sample code given below:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://imran:test_password@mongo:27017/?authSource=admin")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the DB");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// routes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Running on Container!</h1>");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck on this for hours! Setting `db:27017` in the connection string and `restart: always` on the `rest-api-node` makes sure that you connect to the correct IP and makes sure that the node server keeps on trying to connect to your db. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because MongoDB was already running (locally, not on docker) on port 27017 with different credentials and this had precedence over database run on docker.

In such case the solution is either killing local MongoDB or changing ports:

```
  ports:
    - "27018:27017"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by checking my local mongodb's ip using the command `db.runCommand({whatsmyuri: 1})` in **mongosh** and use that instead.