# Node.js Application in container starts and crashes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I have a node.js application talking to mongo database working fine locally. Mongodb is running on my lap top locally and the application is started in vscode with npm run dem. This all works fine.

The application is containerized and starts normally with same commands. However after a few seconds it crashes.
I have tried different format of docker files, docker compose, I have searched google and could not find any solution
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my docker file

```
FROM node:14.15.3
ENV APP_HOME=/home/node/app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_PORT=3002
RUN mkdir -pv $APP_HOME && chown -R node:node $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
USER node
COPY --chown=node:node package.json $APP_HOME/
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force
COPY --chown=node:node . . 
RUN npm run  build
EXPOSE $NODE_PORT
CMD ["node","./dist/server.generated.js"]

Here are the logs

docker run --name test --net app-net  -p 3002:3002 test 
Server started on port 3002.
Material-UI: theme.mixins.gutters() is deprecated.
      
/home/node/app/dist/server.generated.js:1
module.exports=function(e){var t={};function a(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var n=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(n.exports,n,n.exports,a),n.l=!0,n.exports}return a.m=e,a.c=t,a.d=function(e,t,r){a.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},a.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag


docker ps -a 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                      NAMES
b69c46eb2e3b   test      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago   Exited (1) 15 minutes ago                              test
179c0ac2162b   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 days ago      Up 10 days                  0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   app-db
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "express",
    "mongodb",
    "node"
  ],
 
  "main": "./dist/server.generated.js",
  "scripts": {
    "development": "nodemon",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.client.production.js && webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.server.js",
    "start": "node ./node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start ./dist/server.generated.js --name ecommerceapp --log ../logs/app.log ",
    "stop": "node ./node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 stop ecommerceapp",
    "dem": "node ./dist/server.generated.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.3",
    "npm": "8.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
},
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "pm2": "^4.2.0",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.8",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "formidable": "^1.2.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "helmet": "^3.22.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
    "query-string": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.20",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "stripe": "^8.38.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.7.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"

  },
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you ssh into the container and manually start the app? Do you see anything in STDOUT besides what you already posted?

Comment: You have log files ../logs/app.log  beside STDOUT? What do they logs from pm2 say?

Comment: Error response from daemon: Container 6ff2feff4a5d72b2b3ed09c9411cc081b624d2451826677be4c2fa2a73f05954 is not running, when trying to exec and in the preceding stdout I got the following.                                                Error: unable to connect to database: mongodb://localhost:27017/mernproject
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/home/node/app/dist/server.generated.js:1:117406)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:857:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)

Comment: Where do you configure the location of your database?  It's not `localhost`, the application container believes that's the application container.  Also see [MongoDB on with Docker "failed to connect to server [localhost:27017\] on first connect "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011552/mongodb-on-with-docker-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-c).

Comment: I changed database url, rebuild containers, but still I get errors. nodejs   | npm ERR! errno 1
nodejs   | npm ERR! ecommerce@2.0.0 dem: `node ./dist/server.generated.js`
nodejs   | npm ERR! Exit status 1
nodejs   | npm ERR! 
nodejs   | npm ERR! Failed at the ecommerce@2.0.0 dem script.
nodejs   | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
nodejs   | 
nodejs   | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
nodejs   | npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2022-05-03T13_17_04_635Z-debug.log
nodejs exited with code 1