# Containerized App can not access mongo database - ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, docker, express, devops, docker-for-windows

## Mongo database `ECONNREFUSED` for **containerized app**.

I am trying to run simple JS APP using express with mongodb ([GitHub](https://github.com/DevWL/mongodb-express-js-app-basic-setup)). The app is very simple its compose of two short files: index.html and server.js.

When I docker run mongo and mongo-express in containers, and run node express server locally  (Windows 10 host) `npm run start` app works fine under http://localhost:3000. App does connect to database correctly.

However, when building the app in to the image and trying to run it as a container, My app is not able to connect to mongo database (see error log at the very bottom).

The container starts, it even looks like it does listen on the correct port, and it stops after some time seconds. If i exec in to the container and curl the localhost or host IP (hostname -i) at port 3000 it returns the index page content. But mongo database throws an Error: `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017.`

Can anyone tell me what did I miss?

### Recreating the issue—quick run:

1 Get the app from the [GitHub](https://github.com/DevWL/mongodb-express-js-app-basic-setup) repo. 
2 `cd` to the project dir (where the `Dockerfile` is placed). 
3 copy & run:

```
docker rm -f mongodb && docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --net mongo-network --name mongodb mongo
docker rm -f mongo-express && docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=root -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb --net mongo-network --name mongo-express mongo-express
docker rm -f nxapp && docker build -t nxapp . && docker run -p 3000:3000 -di --name nxapp --net mongo-network nxapp
```

The last line above basically: removes old container (if exists) -> builds image (`nxapp`) -> run new app container (`nxapp`)

[image]

If I run the app from my host machine (Windows terminal) `npm run start` in App directory. App will be able to access the mongo database with no error at http://localhost:3000.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13-alpine
EXPOSE 3000

ENV MONGO_DB_USERNAME=root \
    MONGO_DB_PWD=root

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY ./app /home/app

# set default dir so that next commands executes in /home/app dir
# will execute npm install in /home/app because of WORKDIR
RUN apk update
RUN apk add curl

WORKDIR /home/app
RUN npm install

CMD ["node", "/home/app/server.js"]
# CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  # nxapp: # use this if running app from the presisted image instead of building it from git src + Dockerfile. Also be sure to presist database data in the image and import it in Dockerfile.
    # image: devwl/nxapp:1.0 # <dockerhub-username>/<remote-imgname:tag>
    # ports:
    # - 3000:3000

  nxapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always # fixes MongoNetworkError when mongodb is not ready when mongo-express starts
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb

volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

run as `docker compose -f up`

### Error from app container

```
docker logs nxapp
app listening on port 3000!
/home/app/server.js:61
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:878:9)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  reason: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
    name: 'MongoNetworkError',
    errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
    [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

After some time App container `nxapp` will stop due to the error above.

Comment: This sounds very similar to [MongoDB on with Docker "failed to connect to server localhost:27017 on first connect "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011552/mongodb-on-with-docker-failed-to-connect-to-server-localhost27017-on-first-c) -- `127.0.0.1` is your application container, not the MongoDB container.  Both containers are on the same `docker run --net` so you should be able to use the `docker run --name` as a host name.  What code is actually establishing the database connection?

Comment: Why are you tormenting yourself so much by not using docker-compose or any other alike tool?

Comment: @emix I will get there shortly. I need to understand the issue first before I build docker-compose.yaml file.

Comment: Well you will resolve many issues, because of the way how Docker operates on the network layer. Also it's easier to run (one simple command vs lots of smaller ones), easier to work with, to maintain. The configuration can be kept in Git and so on. I'd advice you to learn `docker-compose` ASAP. Also remember that you only need to publish ports that you want to connect to externally. Containers have access to their ports in their network without any publishing required.

Comment: @DavidMaze Not sure if I understand you.  When I run docker run `docker run -p 3000:3000 -di --name nxapp nxapp` (without --net) I get the same error.

Comment: It's quite clear to me that for some reason my app from inside the container have no access or accessing the mongo database incorrectly. I will add connection information for reference.

Comment: @DavidMaze did you mean that In my connection string I need to replace 
mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017 with  "mongodb://root:root@mongodb" ??

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  `localhost` does not usually refer to a different container.

Comment: @DavidMaze this was it. Thanks a lot for pointing this out ! :>. If you would be so kind to add an answer to the question as a reference for others who will encounter similar issue, and which I would gladly accept.

Kind Regards